# Adding a 'sub' <tr> when table data is javascript sourced

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript sourced table, which displays rows based on a number of inputs and if the `<td>` values match the inputs chosen.

This `<script>` is working fine, however I am confused as to how to add in "sub rows". I know this is not correct terminology, but I will try and explain.

Table as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var table = [{
    Col1: 'Col1 Data',
    Col2: [1000, 1500],
    Col3: [30, 60, 90, 180, 360],
    Col4: 'Col4 Data',
    Col5: 'Col5 Data',
    Col6: 'Col6 Data'
  }
];
```

My `<script>` uses the values in Col2 and Col3 to decide whether to display the `<tr>` or not.

I want a row underneath each existing row in my table to show additional data (i.e. "Col7 Data"). How do I achieve this without changes to my script? i.e. create additional rows that show/hide based on whether the row directly before it will show?

I don't want to copy all of the script here ideally, as I just need to know generally how this can be achieved. Can it be achieved just with HTML/CSS for example, or adding some code to check whether "x" row is showing for example?